# set an entity collection to empty in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do you set an entity collection to null? I have tried something like this

```
user.movies = new List<movie>();
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication2.dal.movie>' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<MvcApplication2.dal.movie>'
```

Comment: Just to clarify why you get this error - user.movies isn't a List<movie>, it is an EntityCollection<movie>. So the above code won't work.
user.movies = new EntityCollection<movie>() will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user.movies.Clear();` or `user.movies = null;`